# Modify value of body in django request

Tags: django, python-3.6, django-middleware

**I want to update the value of the json body value in a post Request** in my django API (also using rest framework), right now I'm trying to doing this with a custom middleware. This is my middleware.

```py
def CustomMiddleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):

        print('request: ', request, ' type: ', type(request), ' vars: ', vars(request))
        print('request: ', request.body)
        body = json.loads(request.body)
        body['attr'] = str(body['attr'])+'abc'
        request.body = json.dumps(body)
        response = get_response(request)
        return response

return middleware
```

So when I'm doing a POST request to my API, I got this error:

```
File "/path/models_masking/mask_middleware.py", line 37, in middleware
    request.body = json.dumps(request_updated)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I'd reading and discovered that the `request` object is immutable, so I'm not sure if I'm able to copy to request object, modify the copy and then sent it to the `get_response` function, or maybe there's a better approach to do this, maybe a decorator for my APIView classes.

Could anybody help me out with an elegant solution for this?

### EDIT

The value of 'attr'+'abc' is a new value that is used in a lot of parts of the codebase, my core problem is that I don't want to alter that value in a lot of functions that are in a lot of request endpoints, so my first idea was to update the value of the requests to change value of 'attr' automatically in all of the requests, instead of update each one.

This maybe could be a new question, but if anyone could give a better solution for my problem, i would be thankful.

Comment: Why do you want to do this, can you give an example view?

Comment: Altering the body of a request looks quite "weird". The `HttpRequest` is not completely immutable, for example the `.user` is added by middleware. But nevertheless, altering the request body looks quite "odd".

Comment: Surely you don't want to do this on every single request?

Comment: @IainShelvington yeah, basically the data in the request come somehow encripted, in many of the request actually, I don't want to decrypt manually in all of the POST or PUT functions in my view, that's why I was trying to alter the body's data in a middleware.

Comment: @IainShelvington a view is like
```
from models import Person

class MyView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # this attr var will be the concat with 'abc'
        attr = request.body['attr']
        Person.objects.get(attr=attr)
```

Comment: You would be better off attaching the extra info (if that's the case) to the request object instead of altering the body.

Comment: @JamesLin the problem is that in my app there's already a lot of Code using the the value of 'attr' concat with the 'abc', so, I don't want to modify all of the functions to adapt to the new value of 'attr'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with other people it's not common to alter the body of the request, but if you really need to, then you can set `request._body` since `body` is just a property

```py
    @property
    def body(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_body'):
            if self._read_started:
                raise RawPostDataException("You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream")

            # Limit the maximum request data size that will be handled in-memory.
            if (settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE is not None and
                    int(self.META.get('CONTENT_LENGTH') or 0) > settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE):
                raise RequestDataTooBig('Request body exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE.')

            try:
                self._body = self.read()
            except IOError as e:
                raise UnreadablePostError(*e.args) from e
            self._stream = BytesIO(self._body)
        return self._body
```

Comment: Thank you very much @James, this actually works for my question. I got that is weird to modify the body of a request, that's because part of my question i included if maybe there's a better approach to do this, but maybe i wasn't very clear,  the modified value of 'attr' will be used in another process of the codebase, and i don't want to modify all of the functions to modify the value of 'attr' and then used, thats why i want to alter the request body, actually for a lot of request i need this 'attr' modified. So again, maybe you could give me a better solution for my problem?

Comment: @juancsr yes I know what you mean.

Comment: so basically `attr` is '123', the process behind that request is that i need '123abc' instead of '123', this is basically the same for a lot of request in my app, so i didn't want to change the value of `attr` in every function manually, i was looking for a way to do it automatically for my app`s requests.

Comment: try a global variable or singleton

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer alone didn't made much sense to me. But I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68929118/how-to-change-a-value-of-httprequest-body-in-django) which is based on the accepted answer itself. Attached stackoverflow provides more descriptive answer to owner's problem and also provides a solution for a possible hiccup that can occur while setting body in a request.