# How to change a value of HttpRequest.body in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting a `HttpRequest` object in my view function. I want to change a particular key-value of that request.

Currently I am doing this -

```
def myview(request):
    request._body['key1'] = 'value1' # where 'key1' already exists in request body
    ...
```

But this is giving an error: `TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: `_body` is a stream of bytes: there is no key/value, hence it makes no sense to alter the `_body` like that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem agree.. but I saw an answer suggesting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63255804/modify-value-of-body-in-django-request)

Comment: @AnirbanNagtintinmj: but that answer does not work with `_body` as a key-value pair. You can create a bytes object, and then set it as `request._body = myfancybytesobject`.

Comment: If for example the body is a JSON blob, you can first load the JSON as a dictionary with `data = json.loads(request.body)`, then alter the object (for example `data['key1'] = value1`), and finally put it back in the request: `request._body = json.dumps(data)`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Do you wanna put it in the answer? I can accept then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not alter a the `_body` attribute with `_body['key1'] = 'value1'`, since the body is just the content of the HTTP request, it is not a dictionary-like object. It is a binary stream object.

If that body is in a certain format, for example JSON, you can first parse it to JSON, then alter that JSON object, and then serialize it and set the serialized JSON object as the `._body`. This thus looks like:

```
import json

myjson = json.loads(request.body)
myjson['key1'] = 'value1'
request._body = json.dumps(myjson)
```

For an empty JSON object, we thus can work with:

```
>>> from django.http import HttpRequest
>>> request = HttpRequest()
>>> request._body = b'{}'
>>> hr.body
b'{}'
>>> import json
>>> myjson = json.loads(request.body)
>>> myjson['key1'] = 'value1'
>>> request._body = bytes(json.dumps(myjson), encoding='utf-8')
>>> request.body
b'{"key1": "value1"}'
```

but this will only work (effectively) if the body is indeed a JSON blob. If it is another format, for example urlencoded, then you need another "reader" and "writer".

If you are working in a `ModelViewSet`, you can not apply this "trick" in a method like `create`, since then it is too late: at that moment the parser has already ran and stored the data in `request.data`.

You thus should override the `initialize_request`, for example with:

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

class MyModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    
    def initialize_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        myjson = json.loads(request.body)
        myjson['key1'] = 'value1'
        request._body = bytes(json.dumps(myjson), encoding='utf-8')
        return super().initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. Actual `request.body` didn't change.

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj': I tried this in the Django shell, the session is shared in the edited answer.

Comment: My question states that I need to **change** a value of key. So `'key1'` already exists in `request.body` and I want to change that. Do you have solution for that?

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj': that is exactly the same, since we load the JSON item, and then we *overwrite* the `key1` entry with `value1`, regardless whether it already contains a `key1`, it will take `value1` as value.

Comment: I am sorry, but it doesn't work. If you need any more information I can supply. But it doesn't work currently.

Comment: If it helps, the function is the `create` function of `ModelViewSet`, which I am trying to override in my `views.py` file.

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj': well then it is of course completely to late to set the body of the request, since the Django REST framework will already have read the body and parsed it into data. The request object still exists, but Django already ran boilerplate code to start creating the object.

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj': in that case you need to override the `initialize_request` method that will parse the content to data.

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj': see edit: it is important to do this at the `initialize_request` method, since that method will basically replace the Django HTTPRequest, with Django DRF's request, that has different attributes, methodes, etc.